# Using Get-DnsServerResourceRecord Remotely Against Another Domain

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

Im trying to run the following

```
$secpasswd = 'Test'
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $secpasswd -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ('domain2\nick', $secpasswd)

[scriptblock]$CheckDNS = {
Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -Name 'computername' -ZoneName domain2.local -ComputerName domain2dC.domain2.local }

invoke-command -scriptblock $CheckDNS -Credential $mycreds -ComputerName domain2managementbox.domain2.local
```

This should be running  Get-DnsServerResourceRecord module on the target machine however im getting the following error:

```
Failed to get the zone information for domain2.local on server domain2managementbox.domain2.local.
+ CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (dgtest.local:root/Microsoft/...rResourceRecord) [Get-DnsServerResourceRecord], CimException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : WIN32 5,Get-DnsServerResourceRecord
```

When I run the command on the box itself it works fine and I have the correct permissions.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're attempting to "double hop" with your credentials (from your client machine, to "domain2managementbox.domain2.local" and then again to "domain2dC.domain2.local". This is not permitted using the default kerberos authentication.

Run `Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Client -DelegateComputer domain2managementbox.domain2.local -Force` on your client machine.

Run on `Enable-WSMaCredSSP -Role Server –Force` on "domain2managementbox.domain2.local"

... and then use `-CredSSP` as an additional authentication parameter for `Invoke-Command`.

Comment: I found that I could use Resolve-DnsName to query various records. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/75414495/1703887