# Powershell to bulk query external DNS servers for various type of records?

Tags: powershell, dns

I have a list of Domains I own that require some more information.

The below Script working great for querying but via the Internal Windows DNS server.

How can this be modified to use External DNS servers like 1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8 ?

```
$outFile = 'C:\Temp\DnsRecords.csv'
$zones = @(
    'domain1.net'
    'domain2.com'
    'domain3.org'
)

$rrTypes = @('Soa', 'Mx', 'Txt','NS', 'A', 'CNAME')
$dnsServer = 'PRD-INT-DNS-VM1' #internal DNS server only

$zones | ForEach-Object {
    $zone = $_
    $zoneSOA = (Resolve-DnsName -Name $zone -Type SOA -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).PrimaryServer
    $rrTypes | ForEach-Object {
        $rrType = $_
        Try {
            Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -Zonename $zone -RRType $_ -ComputerName $dnsServer -ErrorAction Stop |
            Select-Object -Property `
            @{n = 'ZoneName'; e = { $zone } },
            @{n = 'ZoneSOA'; e = { $zoneSOA } },
            @{n = 'RecordType'; e = { $rrType } },
            Hostname,
            TimeToLive,
            @{n = 'Data'; e = {
                    $rr = $_
                    Switch ($rr.RecordType) {
                        'A' { $rr.RecordData.IPv4Address.IPAddressToString }
                        'CNAME' { $rr.RecordData.HostnameAlias }
                        'NS'   { $rr.RecordData.NameServer }
                        'SOA'   { $rr.RecordData.PrimaryServer }
                        'SRV'   { $rr.RecordData.DomainName }
                        'MX'   { "$($rr.RecordData.MailExchange); Preference=[$($rr.RecordData.Preference)]" }
                        'PTR'   { $rr.RecordData.PtrDomainName }
                        'AAAA'   { $rr.RecordData.IPv6Address }
                        'TXT'   { $rr.RecordData.DescriptiveText }
                        default { "Unsupported Record Type" }
                    }
                }
            },
            Error
        }
        Catch {
            $_ | Select-Object -Property `
            @{n = 'ZoneName'; e = { $zone } },
            @{n = 'ZoneSOA'; e = { $zoneSOA } },
            @{n = 'RecordType'; e = { $rrType } },
            Hostname,
            TimeToLive,
            Data,
            @{n = 'Error'; e = { $_.Exception.Message } }
        }
    }
} | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path $outFile
ii $outFile
```

Something similar like using: https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to be authenticated to do it; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/31805109/1703887. I found that I could use Resolve-DnsName to query various records. E.g.:

```
PS> Resolve-DnsName -Name google.com -Type MX
Name                                     Type   TTL   Section

    NameExchange                              Preference
----                                     ----   ---   -------    ------------                              ----------
google.com                               MX     300   Answer     smtp.google.com                           10

Name       : smtp.google.com
QueryType  : A
TTL        : 300
Section    : Additional
IP4Address : 142.251.116.26


Name       : smtp.google.com
QueryType  : A
TTL        : 300
Section    : Additional
IP4Address : 142.251.116.27
```